# Unable to select AutoSuggestions loading in UITextfield and UItextview in IOS

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview, autocorrect

We are unable to select auto-suggestion when loading in UITextfields and UITextviews.
We are using IQkeyboardManager for auto-scroll UItextfield visibility.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is by gestureRecognizer

Example:

```
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
   
        let className = String(describing: self.classForCoder)
        if className == "TUIPredictionView" {
            return true
        }
        return (touch.view == self)
        
    }
```